# How to set NSToggleButton to start in state 0 from Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsbutton

How can I in Interface Builder set NSButton of type toggle with Title and Alt.Title to start with the Title (e.g. the state 0)?

The moment I set the button as toggle and set the Alt.Title it displays Alt.Title in View and I can't find the option to set it to start in the 'default' state (state 0).

I could set it pragmatically but is there an option to set it in IB?

I've solved it before but forgot how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does unchecking the "state" checkbox not work for you? That should be all it takes.

Comment: Yes it did, just figured it out since no other option made sense, thanks anyway